# React notification system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notifications, redux, react-router

I have an app like this, and want to use react-notification-system,

And I'm curious about 1 thing, is it possible to turn on notification when something happens in TestComponent?

In other words when something happens in TestComponent how to call parent Component in App.js?

App.js has a routing system

xyz.com/test

```
<Route path='/test' component={TestComponent} />
```

App.js

```
export class App extends Component {
(...)
  <Navbar/>
  <Footer />
  <TestComponent/>

  <ToastNotif
    ref="ToastNotifRef"
    toastNotifStatus={this.state.toastNotifStatus}/>

(...)
```

ToastNotif.js

```
class ToastNotif extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      toastNotifStatus: this.props.toastNotifStatus
    }
}

  componentDidMount(){
    this.notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
     const {notificationList} = newProps;
     console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', newProps);
     const {removeNotification} = this.props;

     if(newProps.toastNotifStatus==='deleted'){
       this.notificationSystem.addNotification({
          title: "xxx!",
          message: 'xxx'
          level: 'success',
          autoDismiss: 0,
          position: 'bl'
       });
     }    
 }

render () {
  console.log('toastnotifstatus (render)',this.state.toastNotifStatus)
    return (
      <div className="notification-component-wrapper">
        <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem"/>
      </div>
    )

  }

}
export default ToastNotif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to update state of the App from `<TestComponent />` you can pass to it a callback as props:

```
export class App extends Component {
 updateToastNotification(newState){
   this.setState({
     toastNotifStatus: newState
   })
 }

 render(){
  return (
    (...)
    <TestComponent onTestComponentChange={this.updateToastNotification.bind(this)}/>
    <ToastNotif
      ref="ToastNotifRef"
      toastNotifStatus={this.state.toastNotifStatus}/>
    (...)
  )
 }
```

and inside `<TestComponent>` when you need to display notification just call `this.props.onTestComponentChange` and pass new notification status.

I would recommend you to get Notification System outside of `<ToastNotif>` and make it standalone component though